# Cannot launch Repl() (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin

I'm writing UITests on Xamarin. I'm trying to launch the Repl window, but it doesn't launch.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xamarin.UITest;
using Xamarin.UITest.Android;
using Xamarin.UITest.Queries;

namespace MurakamiKiev.UITests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        AndroidApp app;

        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest ()
        {
            app = ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp();
        }

        [Test]
        public void ClickingButtonTwiceShouldChangeItsLabel ()
        {
            app.Repl();
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens when you debug that individual test (`ClickingButtonTwiceShouldChangeItsLabel`), is it begin run? Is it faulting/throwing error? ...

Comment: I click tests-run-all tests. It starts debug. Show "selected test started"-"selected test finished" in output . This us all. @SushiHangover

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the the `Repl()` line and "debug" that individual test and then step over it.. what happens?

Comment: Nothin new. Same thing. @SushiHangover

Comment: Grammar, formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with that code. I have seen this happen before but now can't recall the exact resolution. Might have been using NUnit version >= 3. Can you see if you still get the same issue using NUnit version 2.6.3?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was that app.Repl(); was already running in the background, from the previous session.(When you are debugging if you terminate debugger it wont close automatically)

The error I got was:

`System.Exception: 'Error while performing Repl()`

Inner exception

`IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\repl\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.dll because it is being used by another process.`

So you just need to close app.Repl(); command prompt that is running in the background

Comment: thanks, was really confused by this error - why doesn't nunit just start another process? is is significant for testing purposes or a bug?